# Exchange Online Account - Calendar Sync One-Way (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: evolution, calendar

I have a problem with calendar sync with an Exchange account (my professional one) between my computer, the online calendar, and my phone (I have very good reasons to believe it is a problem on the computer side, more later).

To make a long story short, this is the configuration I have now (Ubuntu 22.04.02):

- Exchange account added through "Online Accounts" and, except for the issue I have, it works perfectly for emails, contacts, partly the calendar, etc...
- I mostly use Evolution as my main client, evolution-ews is updated to the last version available in the repositories through apt.

Basically, the issue is that if I add an event to my calendar with my phone (mostly using Samsung Calendar app but I tried with multiple apps), the event does show up in the online version of outlook but it is not visualized in Evolution. I tried adding events in outlook online and the same happens, they are not displayed. When I add events in Evolution, they are properly added to outlook online and my phone, so the problem is only one way.

Does anyone has suggestions on how to solve it or on potential workarounds? Evolution is deeply engrained in my work practices, so I would like to have it sorted out and not just use my phone as a source for the calendar.

Thanks a lot!